# What does DevOps mean

Tags: continuous-integration, release-management, continuous-delivery

You might have recently heard the term “DevOps” being tossed around. I've read a wiki and didn't fully understand what this term means: "Companies with very frequent releases may require a DevOps awareness or orientation."

Can you give a real example to understand what it's like?

Comment: Close collaboration between dev and ops teams (and possibly other). What's the confusion?

Comment: "Companies with very frequent releases may require a DevOps awareness or orientation". What is DevOps awareness and how is it connected to very frequent releases?

Comment: "If you release a lot you need close collaboration between the dev and ops teams."

Comment: Yes, it makes sense. Apart from that it is said that DevOps is a software development method. So I wanted to see examples or some articles what this method contains etc.

Comment: Do you know what "operations" means in a business context?  And development?  Then you know what DevOps means.  Operations is the management of infrastructure which supports production.  Development is the creation of products, which eventually enter production.  DevOps is the "realization" that development requires support and integration with operations.  It is not a "methodology".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's abut semantic not programming

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In a very simple explanation

### - Dev---> to Operation

You will need to automate the deployment for frequently build, batches, hot-fixes or SPs.

### - Operation----> to Dev

You will need to automate and streamline the incident management, the support tickets and the debuging with the dev teams

Comment: https://devops-updates.blogspot.com/2021/01/devops-engineer-list-to-learn.html

Answer (score 4):

As per traditional IT process-

**DEV | Ops**

Imagine the vertical line as a silo between the Development Team and the Operations Team.

To deploy new applications or to deploy enhancements to a current running one developers used to volley their codes over this wall to the court of Operation's team. So collaboration between Dev and Ops was minimal which resulted in issues viz. " Work in test but why the heck its not working in production environment".

This led to frustrations, reinventing the wheel on various counts, multiple reviews, delays in timelines which eventually impacted the ROIs

**Hence**

To negate the above mentioned issues the need of the hour was to bring in a process which infuses a sense of collaboration, innovates to inculcate automation at various stages wherever feasible.

So the silo was broken down resulting in

**DEV-------------->>> is moving towards OPS**

**&**

**OPS-------------->>>>>is moving towards DEV**

Hence the evolution of **"DEVOPS"**